# Clear references to function

Tags: javascript, class, socket.io, reference

I need to clear memory in js, I have classes like this:

```
class A{
  constructor(socket){
    this.initSockets(socket);
  }

  classMethod(){

  }

  initSockets(socket){
    socket.on('name', () => this.classMethod())
  }
}
```

This class cannot be cleaned by the garbage collector, because as I understand socket saves the reference to a class method(memory snapshot point to socket.on), how properly I need "to null" this function, to delete the reference and let garbage collector delete this class? The project becomes a little big, so I can't change the way I use sockets.

Comment: Set your instances of `A` to null?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, in general i have some let a = new A(), and need to delete this, `delete a` will erase only reference, but it will stay in memory, why it doesnt work i have written above

Comment: Just do `socket.off('name')`?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2018 some years have passed and now we write the year 2022;
By now we have stuff like [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap), [WeakSet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) and [WeakRefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakRef)... and the V8 Team has described how to accomplish exactly that with "Weak references and finalizers": https://v8.dev/features/weak-references

This is the procedure they suggest:

```js
const gListenersRegistry = new FinalizationRegistry(({ socket, wrapper }) => {
  socket.removeEventListener('message', wrapper); // 6
});

function addWeakListener(socket, listener) {
  const weakRef = new WeakRef(listener); // 2
  const wrapper = (ev) => { weakRef.deref()?.(ev); }; // 3
  gListenersRegistry.register(listener, { socket, wrapper }); // 4
  socket.addEventListener('message', wrapper); // 5
}

class MovingAvg {
  constructor(socket) {
    this.events = [];
    this.listener = (ev) => { this.events.push(ev); }; // 1
    addWeakListener(socket, this.listener);
  }
}
```

For more details read the article above.